# Industry and Sector Details using Pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Is there a way by which we can get industry and sector information for a stock using pine script

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to get?

Comment: Sector and Industry of a stock using pine

Comment: Can you provide a single example of those `industry` and `sector`? Are those information available anywhere? (if yes, where, provide and URL).

Comment: Yes, those are available in tradingview, opening the general data tab of the stock

Answer (score 0):

`pinescript` offers many financial data but industry and sectors are not part of those.

For the list of available data please see [this](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000564727-what-financial-data-is-available-in-pine/) and [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html#request-financial).